# Opencart module needed : electronic transactions

Tags: opencart

Payment gateways I understand, what I need is too do is connect to a webservice before and after my transaction is paid for, first connect asks if item is in stock, second connect (after money is taken) will dispatch the product via the webservice...

My Question :

Modules appear to be used mostly for trivial front end stuff like 'social networking plugins' and the like, while payment gateways are 'modules' in a way that are only loaded on checkout. My requirements could be put inside a payment module, but I'l much prefer to create a plugin that is payment gateway agnostic.

Any good advice? Tutorials all appear to be 'how to use the front and backend' type stuff, is there online resources to explain module development further... or...

Is there a module or extension that does this sort of thing already that I could check out how it works?

I'm very new to opencart (installed 2 days ago for the first time, v1.5.5.1) and it appears my only option is to read the php like it's a harry potter novel to get the job done, and there are little to no comments in the code, and the MVC architecture is quite new to me as well.

P.S. I've already installed vQmod, and understand how plugins use it and why, dreading having to use it though, worried upgrading will mean redevelopment (you never know what they change), but thats beside the point, if you suggest vQmod, feel free to give me details, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to have a quick start guide for OpenCart development, you can check out my article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru/13484904#13484904). As for vQmod changing drastically, I can assure you that it won't (unlike opencart's somewhat hectic changes between even minor versions). vQmod is authored by myself and Qphoria and is backward compatible right to version 1.0

To do what you've suggested, the simplest thing to me would still be to use a payment gateway if that's what you're developing rather than a module. They are essentially the same thing, just in a different area of OpenCart's admin and folder structure so it makes little difference how you do it, just more aesthetically pleasing. If your payment gateway requires data passed via a `POST` then check out the `PayPal Standard` files on how to do this - if it's via `cURL` then check out the `PayPal Pro` files

Comment: thanks Jay, I meant if they upgrade opencart, but anyway... are you suggesting I modify a payment gateway to do payment AND online transaction, or develop a 'payment gateway agnostic' module (modelled on paypal example) alongside whatever I'm going to be using for taking money? It's just the commercial people haven't decided what payment gateway we going to use yet :(

Comment: Ah I see. You'd be best modelling off one of those mods rather than modifying one in my opinion. That's how I've done it in the past at least